# DevExpress AspxGridView GetRowValues during BeforePerformDataSelect Event

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

So, I have a master grid and a detail grid within that master grid.

I am grabbing the masterkey from my parent grid via the BeforePerformDataSelect and placing this value into a session variable.  At that point I also need to grab a value from the specific row that I am on.  Lets call that variable SENT_DATE.

Here is some sample code.

```
Protected Sub gvDetails_BeforePerformDataSelect(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim gvDetails As ASPxGridView = (TryCast(sender, ASPxGridView))
        Session("ID_NUMBER") = gvDetails.GetMasterRowKeyValue
        Session("SENT_DATE") = gvDetails.GetRowValues("SENT_DATE")
End Sub
```

I have worked with DevExpress products a lot before but it has been quite some time.  If I remember correctly, normally I just grab the e.VisibleIndex and I am able to go from there but in this specific event I am unable to grab this.  I know the above code is incorrect for grabbing the variable SENT_DATE, but I am not sure what to do here.

Any ideas, advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.  I have searched the DevExpress forums deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FocusedRowIndex](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FocusedRowIndextopic) property.

```cs
Session("SENT_DATE") = gvDetails.GetRowValues(gvDetails.FocusedRowIndex, "SENT_DATE")
```

Comment: Gosh, great way of doing this, wish I would have had this earlier.  I already went a different route with this, but thank your very much for this solution I am sure I will use this in the future.